# How to connect VC throw navController in tabBarController to pass data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to change text of label in VC when tabBar item tapped. But after i embedded UINavigationController to VC, i'm having crash when tapping on tabBar (Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value). Does anybody know how to fix that? [This is a photo of crash line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpomY.png)

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    
    
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3{
            
            let navVC = tabBarController.viewControllers![3] as? UINavigationController
            let bagPageVC = navVC?.topViewController as? bagPage
            
            bagPageVC!.stringCountOfHP = "\(String(bagPageVC!.countArray)) items in bag"
            bagPageVC?.tableView.reloadData()
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: either `let bagPageVC = navVC.topViewController as? bagPage` or `tabBarController.viewControllers![3] as! UINavigationController` this must be returning `nil`, add an `if let` or `guard let` to debug further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help your code from crashing,

```
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3{
            if let navVC = tabBarController.viewControllers?[3] as? UINavigationController,
               let bagPageVC = navVC.topViewController as? bagPage {
            bagPageVC.countOfHP.text = "\(String(bagPageVC.countArray)) items in bag"

        }
    }
```

There might be multiple reasons for crash

1.`tabBarController.viewControllers` might be returning nil,

2. `tabBarController.viewControllers![3] as! UINavigationController` Though there exists a view controller at index 3 it might not be `UINavigationController` or subclass of `UINavigationController`
3. bagPageVC! might be nil and hence force unwrapping might be crashing it because `navVC.topViewController` is not `bagPage`

Without taking a proper look into your ViewController set up n hierarchy it wont be possible to help you further than this.

Code above will safely unwrap all the optionals, so it wont crash your code

**EDIT 1:**

Issue happens for the first time, when you tap on tab bar at index 3, `ViewController` at that index is not yet visible on screen, so obviously all its `IBOutlet`s are nil, and when you blindly access the implicit optional IBOutlet `bagPageVC.countOfHP` it crashes.

**What can you do?**

Two possible solutions I can think of

**Solution 1:**

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3,
           let bagPageVC = (viewController as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? bagPage {
            let _ = bagPageVC.view //this statement will force the view controller to load its view hence `ViewDidLoad` will be called automatically for the first time (which anyway would have called you are just fast tracking it
            bagPageVC.countOfHP.text = "\(String(bagPageVC.countArray)) items in bag"
        }
    }
```

`didSelect viewController` will be called everytime user selects a different tab, but `let _ = bagPageVC.view` will cause `ViewDidLoad` to be called only once (once view is loaded, when you access `.view` it will simply return the view)

Though this code will work absolutely fine without any issue, I am not very big fan of meddling with View cycle, hence Solution 2

**Solution 2:**

Check if the implicit optional `IBOutlet` is `nil`, if it is not then simply set the text, else pass the text to `bagPageVC` and set it in `ViewDidLoad`

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3,
           let bagPageVC = (viewController as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? bagPage {
            if let countLabel = bagPageVC.countOfHP {
                  countLabel.text = "\(String(bagPageVC.countArray)) items in bag"
            }
            else {
                 bagPageVC.countInfo = "\(String(bagPageVC.countArray)) items in bag"
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in your `bagPageVC` declare a variable named `countInfo` as `String?`

`var countInfo: String? = nil`

And in `ViewDidLoad` you can simply set

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     countOfHP.text = countInfo
}
```

`ViewDidLoad` is called only once in ViewController's life cycle, so you dont have to worry about resetting `countInfo` in subsequent `didSelect viewController` call

Which one will you choose I leave it to you :)

Comment: it's crashed. i tryed to print bagPageVC, it printed right VC

Comment: Did it crash even after using this code? Can you add a screenshot of the crash

Comment: i added screenshot to question

Comment: Crash clearly shows your `countOfHP` label is nil, is this an IBOutlet? Is it connected properly? IBOutlet can be nil if its not connected to UIComponent in story board or if UI is not loaded yet, but if this is one of the tab bar controllers view controller I believe ViewDidLoad is called on all the ViewControllers already, so the only possibility left is IBOutlet is not connected

Comment: no. i re added IBOutlets and it's still crashing in the same line

Comment: can you try writing `countOfHP.text = "abcd"` in `ViewDidLoad` of `bagPageVC` ? And tell me if its still crashing?

Comment: don't forget that i have navController between vc and tabbar. everything worked clearly before adding nav controller

Comment: Okay one last try, can you put a break points in `ViewDidLoad` of `bagPageVC` and on `didSelect viewController` and check which one gets called first? My guess is your `bagPageVC` is not yet loaded and `didSelect viewController` gets called hence its IBOutlet is `nil` But that would be strange case :|

Comment: breakpoint in didSelect function popped up with green color

Comment: is that means that didselect function loads first

Comment: yes, even before ViewDidLoad of `bagPageVC` that is strange, how have you added the navigation controller?

Comment: do u have any ideas how to fix the issue

Comment: @МухаммедАралбек Added a new answer with two working solutions, check and decide which one you want

Comment: Thank u a lot for help. i used first method as a solution.

Comment: @МухаммедАралбек am really sorry, I thought you down voted the question  Thanks for the upvote again really sorry I thought u down voted it :(